# Angularjs 2: select not updating with selected value in ion-select Ionic 2?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, ionic2

I have below code which is working so far, but have small problem which I cannot figure it out. It's not updating (set the selected value into ion-select) ion-select after user chooses one option? Basically UI is not updating with selected value?

```
<ion-item>
<ion-label>Classifications</ion-label>
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="selectedItem" #item (change)="onChange(selectedItem)">
<ion-option *ngFor="#item of items" [value]="item">{{item}}</ion-option>
</ion-select>
</ion-item>

onChange(selectedItem) {
   console.log('Selected item: '+selectedItem);
}
```

Out put properly displays as user select, any ideas what I'm missing here?

**update**

```
<ion-item> 
  <ion-label>Gender</ion-label> 
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="gender"> 
    <ion-option value="f" checked="true">Female</ion-option> 
    <ion-option value="m">Male</ion-option> 
  </ion-select> 
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Is `onChange(selectedItem)` being called? `selectedItem` should already be updated by `<ion-select [(ngModel)]="selectedItem"`. `(change)="onChange(selectedItem)` shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: yes, onChange(selectedItem) is called, but if I removed that line how do I get selected value, thus console.log('Selected item: '+selectedItem); in constructor gives this ReferenceError: selectedItem is not defined.

Comment: To get rid of the error you'd need to change `(change)="onChange(selectedItem)">` to `(change)="onChange($event)">` or `(change)="onChange(item.value)">` (I don't know what the property names of `<ion-item>` actually are or what value it provides for the event.

Comment: You could also try if changing the event `(ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">` also calls `onChange()`.

Comment: It didnt work. This simple example of select, which already selected female by default.<ion-item>
      <ion-label>Gender</ion-label>
      <ion-select [(ngModel)]="gender">
        <ion-option value="f" checked="true">Female</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="m">Male</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>

Comment: I don't know what you mean. What didn't work? I suggested three versions above. I added the code to your question because bigger code blocks in comments are unreadable. I don't know what this code should demonstrate though.

Comment: I mean when user selects a value it should display in the drop down component (in my case ion-select component), its not working although i could get selected value to console. Example demonstrate how value can be set to ion-select by default, thought you could get an idea.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104796/discussion-between-kanishka-raveendra-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: any one can help me with this issue please!!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43563519/how-to-load-data-in-select-item-in-ionic-2-and-know-the-selected-item

Answer (score 6):

For Ionic 2 beta 10 next works for me:

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Fest</ion-label>
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="festId" (ionChange)="festSelected($event, festId)">
        <ion-option *ngFor="let fest of festList" value="{{fest.id}}">
            {{fest.title}}
        </ion-option>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issues after adding `(ionChange)=""` it started working for me.

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="msgType" (ionChange)="getListOfMsg()">
```