# how to load data in select item in ionic 2 and know the selected item?

Tags: ionic2, items

My current attempt below

**page.html**

```
<form (ngSubmit)="InsertLocation()" #registerForm="ngForm">
     <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
             <img src="assets/img/1.jpg" />
              <ion-list>
                  <ion-item>
                     <ion-label>Chauffeur</ion-label>
                     <ion-select [(ngModel)]="selectedvalue"name="chauff">
                         <ion-option *ngFor="let item of chauffeurs"[value]="item.nom_chauffeur">
                         {{item.nom_chauffeur}}
                         </ion-option>
                     </ion-select>
                   </ion-item>
            <ion-list>
         <ion-row>
       <ion-col>
       <button ion-button class="submit-btn" type="submit" 
       [disabled]="!registerForm.form.valid">Inserer</button>
</form>
```

**page.ts**

```
  LoadChauffeurs(id){
  this.data.LoadChauffeur().subscribe(
      data => {
          this.chauffeurs= data; 
      },
      err => {
          console.log(err);
      },
      () => console.log('success!')
  );
}
```

knowing the result of data is an array like this

```
[{
     "id_chauffeur":6,
      "nom_chauffeur":"ggg", 
      "num_tel":2563,"id_chef":10
}]
```

and my service that i call it data in page.ts
**data-service.ts**

```
LoadChauffeur(id) {

  var url = 
   'http://localhost/PFEBACKEND/retrievechauffeurs.php?'key=random&id='+id;
      var response = this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json());
      return response;

 }
```

[image: this the result i get]

Comment: where is your `selectedvalue` code? What is the model?

Comment: i don't have !! could you send me an example